# net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 unexpected token: DAY

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

```
public void sqlData() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
{

    Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://path;
    String qry = "SELECT Patient.NAME AS patient, Patient.DISEASE AS 
    disease FROM Patient, Doctor WHERE 
    Patient.DISEASE=Doctor.SPECIALIZATION";
    try{

      Statement st = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(qry);
      DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)appoint_table.getModel();
      int x =1;
      while(rs.next())
      {
        String rrr = rs.getString("patient");
        System.out.println(rrr);

      }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: when i run this code, this error is occur:-    " net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 unexpected token: DAY"

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the actual code that causes the exception (your code wouldn't compile), and the exact and complete stack trace of the exception (replace `System.out.println(e);` by `e.printStackTrace()`, or better, don't catch the exception)

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that your posted code will throw that exception, but I try to answer while assuming way too much details to do it correctly. Anyway...

---

I assume:

1. you are using JPA
2. you set `delimited-identifiers`
3. you also are using EclipseLink as implementation.

If so, do as follows:

Include a target-database entry in persistence.xml:

```
    <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.AccessPlatformDelimiterConfig"/>
```

Add a new class to your classpath:

```
package org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database;

public class AccessPlatformDelimiterConfig extends AccessPlatform {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7034590043310425678L;

    public AccessPlatformDelimiterConfig() {
        super();
        this.tableQualifier = "";
        this.startDelimiter = "";
        this.endDelimiter = "";
    }
}
```